# mvc4 multiple ifs in document.ready giving syntax error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing code for a view in document.ready I write the following conditions but the code is not executed and even in design time it is showing in green the errors I have given below.
This is mvc4
Please Help.  thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    @{ 
        if(ViewBag.itemName!="" || ViewBag.itemName!=null)
        {
            if(ViewBag.itemName=="PORTFOLIO")
            {
                //showing expected expression
                <text> $('#_ktPortfolio').val("@ViewBag.itemId");</text>; 
            }

            if(ViewBag.itemName=="PHASE")
            {
                //showing expected expression  
                <text> $('#_ktPhases').val("@ViewBag.itemId");</text>;
            }
        } // end of if //this is showing syntax error
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks fine to me - you could try closing and re-opening the `.cshtml` file. Sometimes VS gets confused.

Comment: did the same even closed visual studio but it persists

Comment: I don't think this code is wrong - I would check for a problem with the other code in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things I'd change/check.

1. Your check for a null or empty string isn't needed.
2. It also looks like you've get some extra semi colons after your `</text>` tags.
3. You are also switching between `'` and `"` for your strings in JavaScript. I'd pick `'` and stick with (except when you can't). I find it helps make it clear what is run on the client and what is run on the server.
4. I'd also make sure you have this wrapped in a client side script tag.

   ```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       @{
           if(ViewBag.itemName=="PORTFOLIO"){
               <text> $('#_ktPortfolio').val('@ViewBag.itemId');</text> //showing expected expression
           }
           if(ViewBag.itemName=="PHASE"){
              <text> $('#_ktPhases').val('@ViewBag.itemId');</text> //showing expected expression  
           }
       }
   });
   ```